# What causes the phenomena of a ring appearing around the shadow of an airplane

Tags: optics

So I was sitting in an airplane and I saw a ring appearing around the shadow of the plane on the clouds. What causes this phenomena? I've added an edited image, so the effect is more pronounced. [image: Photo of rings appearing around the shadow of a plane.]

Comment: You might be interested in: [What is the explanation of the glory (optical phenomenon)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256636/what-is-the-explanation-of-the-glory-optical-phenomenon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory_(optical_phenomenon)).
You can tell it apart from a [circular rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Full-circle_rainbow) because of the thickness of the colours relative to the radius of the turn, the repetition of the colours, and the way it seems to appear on a cloud.  It's much more consistent with pictures of a glory (rainbows have a much wider circle they form due to their mechanism).

It's an interference pattern caused by refraction of light in the small droplets.

I also meant to add this to my answer. [What is the explanation of the glory (optical phenomenon)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256636/what-is-the-explanation-of-the-glory-optical-phenomenon) (Diracology also linked in comments).

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is called a Glory.  It is caused by back scattering from individual water droplets.  There is a lot more detail to be found on this site: http://www.atoptics.co.uk/droplets/gloab.htm
Wikipedia also has an article on it, which claims that the physics is not fully understood.